# Bounding Elements in a Banach Space in Terms of Their Images Under a Bounded Linear Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be Banach spaces and let $ T : X \to Y $ be a bounded linear operator.  I am currently looking for known results that allows me to bound the norms of elements in $ X $ in terms of the norms of their images under $ T $ in $ Y $.  I have the following two results:

1. If $ T $ is surjective, then by the Open Mapping Theorem, there exists a constant $ K > 0 $ (dependent only on $ T $) such that for every $ y \in Y $, there exists an $ x \in X $ with $ T(x) = y $ and $ \| x \| \leq K \| y \| = K \| T(x) \| $.
2. If $ T $ is injective and $ T $ has closed range, then there exists a constant $ K > 0 $ such that for every $ x \in X $, $ \| x \| \leq K \| T(x) \| $.

I vaguely remember some other related results, but I cannot seem to find them.  If anyone knows of any similar results, I'd greatly appreciate it!  Thanks!

Comment: Consider $\mathrm{H} = \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mathbf{R}$ as a Hilbert sum. Define $f:\mathrm{H} \to \mathrm{H}$ by $f((a_n)) = (\frac{1}{n} a_n).$ Then $f$ is continuous (in fact, $\|f\| = 1$) but the elements $v_k$ whose $p$th entry is $p^{-2}$ for $k \leq p$ and zero otherwise, satisfy $\|v_k\| = \sum_{p \geq k} p^{-2} \asymp k^{-1}$ yet $\|f(v_k)\| = \sum_{p\geq k} p^{-3} \asymp k^{-2}.$ Hence, to bound the elements in the domain in terms of their images, you need constants depending on the particular vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement: there exists $c>0$ such that
$$
\|x\| \le c\|Tx\| \quad \forall x
$$
is equivalent to fact that $T$ is injective and has closed range.

Assume the inequality is satisfied. Then clearly $T$ is injective. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $(Tx_n)$ converges. Then $(Tx_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, the inequality implies that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since the space $X$ is complete,
$x_n\to x$ and $Tx_n\to Tx$. Hence the range is closed.

Hence, in order to obtain the inequality, you have to prove that the range of $T$ is closed.